# How to search for non-workspace files with Ctrl-P in VS Code?

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to search for files (filename search) that are not in the current workspace? I would like to be able to access some files at all times, however I do not want to constantly creating symlinks across workspaces. I am also on Windows and symlinks requires admin rights plus Git does not like them. So I am looking for a VS Code native solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well from what i have seen the only time you can get only files in the workspace and files that were previously open in that workspace (so for example settings.json)